# BigQueryGetDataOperator project ID

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow-2.x

I read the document about `BigQueryGetDataOperator` and used it. The problem is I didn't know have to pass my select `projectID` to this operator. So this returns non exist table.

It default use: `project_a.dataset_b.table_c`.

With I would like to change it to: `project_d.dataset_b.table_c`.

Comment: For your requirement, to Access resources in another project  you can use  the 'bigquery_conn_id' parameter from the [operator](http://airflow.apache.org/integration.html?highlight=bigquery#bigquerygetdataoperator). In there you need to specify a new "conn_id" that you can create by following [steps.](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to query the table in "project_d", you have to create a new airflow connexion and use a service account created in "project_d" with the proper roles instead of the current connexion using a service account in "project_a".